# Enum can be passed only by right reference

Tags: c++11

I would kindly ask someone to explain me a bit why an enum can only be passed by right reference and not as simple reference ?

```
 namespace n1
{
    enum e1
    {
        f = 1,
        f1
    };
}
void f(n1::e1&& e)
{
    std::cout<<static_cast<int>(e);

}
int main()
{
   f(n1::e1::f1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should either use a enum class instead of a namespace/enum pattern OR ignore the cast and cheat a lil by using this pattern so you don't have to cast it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enum`s are constants so you can't take it as `n1::e1&` but as `const n1::e1&`:

```
void f(const n1::e1& e) {
    std::cout<<static_cast<int>(e);
}
```

Comment: Agree with the answer, but I'd recommend to pass `enum` (or any other small object like `std::span`, `std::string_view` etc) by value.

Comment: @Quarra When it's `const`, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

**Enumerations are integral constants** :

- an enum parameter of a function must be constant

**Remark** : you don't have to cast the enum to print his value

```cpp
void f(const n1::e1& e) {
    std::cout<< e ;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what "Rem" means? Is it 'reminder', or 'remember', or something else?